# extract the month of a string

Tags: regex, r, date

I need to extract the month from a series of strings in the format:

```
Tue Jan 05 03:29:10 CET 2016
```

I have tried with:

```
#extracting the second capturing group
sub("([A-z]{3})\\s([A-z]{3})","\\2","Tue Jan 05 03:29:10 CET 2016")

#or just the first whitespace with the Month:
sub("\\s([A-z]{3})","\\2","Tue Jan 05 03:29:10 CET 2016")
```

My expected output, in this case would be:

```
"Jan"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Or we can use the `month()` function from `lubridate`, given we convert our string to a `Date` object first.

```
library(lubridate)
month(as.Date("Tue Jan 05 03:29:10 CET 2016", "%a %b %d"), label = TRUE)
#[1] Jan
```

Or in `base` R as suggested by @HaddE.Nuff:

```
format(as.Date("Tue Jan 05 03:29:10 CET 2016", "%a %b %d"), "%b")
```

Comment: Can't we just do `months(as.Date("Tue Jan 05 03:29:10 CET 2016", "%a %b %d"))` from base R too?

Comment: Or `month.abb[as.POSIXlt("Tue Jan 05 03:29:10 CET 2016", format = "%a %b %d")$mon + 1]`

Comment: @DavidArenburg `POSIXlt` is always scary to me since they're such huge objects...

Answer (score 1):

You need to match the whole string and capture what you need into a capturing group to restore its value with a backreference later.

Use

```
> sub("^[[:alpha:]]{3}\\s+([[:alpha:]]{3})\\b.*", "\\1", "Tue Jan 05 03:29:10 CET 2016")
[1] "Jan"
```

The pattern means:

- `^` - match start of string
- `[[:alpha:]]{3}` - match 3 letters
- `\\s+` - match 1+ whitespace
- `([[:alpha:]]{3})\\b` - match and capture into Group 1  three letters as a whole word (`\b` is a word boundary marker)
- `.*` - 0+ any characters (up to the end of the string)

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/gM3qP3/2)

**ALSO** please note that [`[A-z]` should be avoided](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29771901/why-is-this-regex-allowing-a-caret/29771926#29771926).

Answer (score 1):

A very intuitive suggestion. That will match the first three letter of a month. Might not work for every case but it is simple to come up with.

```
 > aa <- regexpr("Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec","Tue Jan 05 03:29:10 CET 2016")
 > regmatches("Tue Jan 05 03:29:10 CET 2016",aa)
#[1] "Jan"
```

Comment: Only if we're always in an English locale.

Comment: @HaddE.Nuff granted, your suggestion is more general.

Answer (score 1):

Try this `sub`:

```
sub("... (...).*", "\\1", "Tue Jan 05 03:29:10 CET 2016")
## [1] "Jan"
```